# Arcore failed to get enough keypoints from target image

Tags: arcore

Arcore failed to get enough key-points from target image.
The image is text on a black background.... is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: I do not know if you are using Unity or Android or something else but what is the [score](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/) of your image. Have you specified the size of the image while creating the database? that helps as well.

Comment: i am using android .... and the tool says that "Arcore failed to get enough key-points from target image"

Comment: Only solution is changing your image i believe

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by increasing the size of the image to be at least 300x300px, found this in the "**choosing a good reference image**" section of the [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/arcore-by-google-building-augmented-images-applica):

> - image’s resolution must be at least 300 x 300 pixels.

The goal was to produce the simplest image I can to track. As I was making changes to the image, I kept checking the score of the image via arcoreimg tool.
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/augmented-images/arcoreimg
note that you'll need to cd into the location of the .exe file before running the command. On windows you may need to run it with "./" as shown below.

> ./arcoreimg.exe eval-img --input_image_path=dog.png

Final result:
[simple trackable image rated at 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y8RM.png)